# Como esmaecer alguns componentes no fundo para destacar um TPanel sobre eles?

Tags: delphi

Tenho uma tela principal, com alguns TPanels e outros componentes, e um desses TPanels gostaria de criar uma tela de login. Ao chamar esse TPanel de login por cima dos demais componentes do formulário eu estou desabilitando os componentes de baixo, como se fosse um "modal" usado em sites. Mas eu gostaria também de deixar os componentes de baixo esmaecidos (escurecidos). Existe alguma forma simples de fazer isso usando o Delphi 7? Já pesquisei bastante e não encontrei, apenas métodos de animação.

Veja abaixo um exemplo do que gostaria de fazer:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agradeço desde já qualquer ajuda!

Comment: Opa, Guy, eu faço com `forms`, na minha tela principal, crio uma `procedure` para abrir a tela, com opções de centralização, etc. Ao abrir meu form de login, no create crio outro Form em tempo de execução, chamado de Background, e nele coloco o tamanho do meu form da tela principal, com `AlphaBlend` e `AlphaBlendValue  := 200`, e outros parâmetros para ficar bonitinho. No formClose da tela de Login, mando matar essa form de trás. O que acha? Se quiser depois posso postar um exemplo...

Comment: @David, vou primeiro tentar uma forma de fazer isso usando Panels. Se realmente não for possível então partirei para outra abordagem, como essa que informou (já havia visto em um fórum sobre isso). Obrigado de qualquer forma! Abraço!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olá, depois da imagem que você enviou quebrei a cabeça.

A solução mais simples que encontrei foi usar o Project Jedi que adiciona muitos componentes.

A ideia foi colocar um Panel com alClient transparente e dentro dele uma imagem semitransparente e ficou assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O código:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, pngimage, ExtCtrls, JvExExtCtrls, JvExtComponent, JvPanel,
  StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    btn1: TButton;
    jvpnl1: TJvPanel;
    Button2: TButton;
    Image1: TImage;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  jvpnl1.Align := alClient;
  jvpnl1.Visible := True;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  jvpnl1.Visible := False;
end;

procedure TForm1.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Close;
end;

end.
```

Arquivo Unit1.dmf

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 192
  Top = 117
  Width = 829
  Height = 413
  Caption = 'Form1'
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'MS Sans Serif'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object Button1: TButton
    Left = 152
    Top = 40
    Width = 75
    Height = 25
    Caption = 'Button1'
    TabOrder = 0
    OnClick = Button1Click
  end
  object btn1: TButton
    Left = 256
    Top = 152
    Width = 75
    Height = 25
    Caption = 'btn1'
    TabOrder = 1
    OnClick = btn1Click
  end
  object jvpnl1: TJvPanel
    Left = 456
    Top = 80
    Width = 337
    Height = 201
    Transparent = True
    BevelOuter = bvNone
    TabOrder = 2
    Visible = False
    object Image1: TImage
      Left = 0
      Top = 0
      Width = 337
      Height = 201
      Align = alClient
      Picture.Data = {
        0A54504E474F626A65637489504E470D0A1A0A0000000D49484452000000F000
        0000C80806000000D67C6C52000002424944415478DAEDD3010D00301003A1BE
        7F6B13351D9780076EDB1B90741318B204863081214C60081318C20486308121
        4C60081318C204863081214C60081318C204863081214C60081318C204863081
        214C60081318C204863081214C60081318C204863081214C60081318C2048630
        81214C60081318C204863081214C60081318C204863081214C60081318C20486
        3081214C60081318C204863081214C60081318C204863081214C60081318C204
        863081214C60081318C204863081214C60081318C204863081214C60081318C2
        04863081214C60081318C204863081214C60081318C204863081214C60081318
        C204863081214C60081318C204863081214C60081318C204863081214C600813
        18C204863081214C60081318C204863081214C60081318C204863081214C6008
        1318C204863081214C60081318C204863081214C60081318C204863081214C60
        081318C204863081214C60081318C204863081214C60081318C204863081214C
        60081318C204863081214C60081318C204863081214C60081318C20486308121
        4C60081318C204863081214C60081318C204863081214C60081318C204863081
        214C60081318C204863081214C60081318C204863081214C60081318C2048630
        81214C60081318C204863081214C60081318C204863081214C60081318C20486
        3081214C60081318C204863081214C60081318C204863081214C60081318C204
        863081214C60081318C204863081214C60081318C204863081214C60081318C2
        04863081214C60081318C20486308121EC030928A029907BE5A9000000004945
        4E44AE426082}
      Stretch = True
      Transparent = True
    end
    object Button2: TButton
      Left = 64
      Top = 32
      Width = 75
      Height = 25
      Caption = 'Button2'
      TabOrder = 0
      OnClick = Button2Click
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Obrigado por tentar ajudar, mas não sei se entendi muito bem... Você jogou o JvPanel em alClient e dentro do JvPanel uma imagem também em alClient, e essa imagem é um PNG ou GIF semitransparente? Ou como você fez para a imagem ficar semitransparente? Obrigado!

Comment: Eu criei uma imagem semitransparente 80% do preto em PNG. Se quiser eu te envio.

Comment: Ok, não precisa, vou tentar fazer o mesmo aqui. Mas desde já agradeço a atenção!

Comment: O Delphi 7 não tem suporte nativo ao PNG. Instalei um componente chamado pngimage, mas não estou conseguindo simular o que você fez. Mesmo com a imagem PNG 80% transparente e o JvPanel transparente, ao compilar o projeto a tela fica preta. Por favor, qual componente com suporte ao formato PNG você está usando?

Comment: Eu também estou com Delphi 7 e uso o PNGComponents:   https://www.dropbox.com/s/v2mzussb0wf3wk3/PngComponents.rar?dl=0

Comment: A biblioteca base desse componente que está usando é a mesma que eu instalei, porém a minha biblioteca está atualizada. Mas infelizmente não consegui fazer funcionar de forma alguma. Por favor, poderia incluir na resposta o código do arquivo DFM (unit1.dfm) para que eu possa analisar se tem alguma propriedade, de algum dos componentes, fora do padrão? Obrigado!

Comment: Coloquei o DFM.....olha que estou tentando usar componentes apenas do Delphi e nada... o dia todo tentando... acho que essa é a solução para o Delphi 7.... li que em outras versões podemos usar o AlphaBlend apenas para o form e mantendo os objetos sólidos.

Comment: Versões do Delphi com Firemonkey já fazem isso com poucos cliques e pouca programação. Não sei se é possível usa-lo em seu caso, mas, caso sim, use! Para mim, Firemonkey é hoje o que a VCL deveria ter sido no passado, embora, Delphi 7 sempre foi o meu preferido até as versões XE amadurecerem mais e se tornarem usáveis para mim, além do fato, claro, de eu poder distribuir meus sistemas também para OSX e outras plataformas.